# install pipewire+wireplumber and remove pulseaudio safely

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

Are there any ways to safely install pipewire+wireplumber and safely remove **pulseaudio** for ubuntu. i am trying to fix bluetooth connection to my headset. Or are there any ways to debug with pulseaudio directly.

[bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2035334#p2035334](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2035334#p2035334)

I see several issues listed here:

[Pipewire + wireplumber don't work on Ubuntu 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441732/pipewire-wireplumber-dont-work-on-ubuntu-22-10)

[Ubuntu 22.10 Pipewire / Wireplumber: a2dp-sink profile connect failed. Device or resource busy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451783/ubuntu-22-10-pipewire-wireplumber-a2dp-sink-profile-connect-failed-device-or)

[Switching from pulseaudio to pipewire deletes my GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444357/switching-from-pulseaudio-to-pipewire-deletes-my-gui)

[Pipewire + wireplumber don't work on Ubuntu 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441732/pipewire-wireplumber-dont-work-on-ubuntu-22-10)

Comment: Maybe [have a look here](https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e)? And please add the details as an answer if it works.

Comment: I guess the "Server" check works, but it did not remove pulseaudio